# How to parse JSON objects with double quotes in one of its property values

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have a json string, with one of its property values having a `double quote` in it, I am not able to parse it.

For example, if my object is `{ "Name" : "Six \" Pipe" }` then the following gives me an error - `Unexpected token P`.

```
var str = '{ "Name" : "Six \" Pipe" }';
JSON.parse(str); //error
$.parseJSON(str); //error
```

The string is formed in a razor view as follows -

```
 var str = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

And then in JavaScript I am doing

```
var obj = JSON.parse('@(Html.Raw(str))');
```

How can I parse such strings?

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the backslashes since in JS it will only `\"` will be converted to `"` and will make the JSON incorrect. [The blackslash is discarded by javascript](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.4).

so the correct string would be-

```
var str = '{ "Name" : "Six \\" Pipe" }';
JSON.parse(str); //works
```

**Edit:**

So, if you want to create a literal backslash in JS, you have to escape it. You can do this while creating this string and double-escaping the key's value. *One way* to tackle this could be -

To html encode the strings (key values) just like: `&quot;` instead of `\"` etc. This seems straight forward to me with .Net. I'm not sure but [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could help. 
Then on the javascript side you could be able to parse straight away- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRNty/)

Comment: this is misleading - the double backslash is only needed because the input is a _JS string literal_.  The "wire format" for JSON doesn't require it, as you would see if you were to call `JSON.stringify()` on the output of `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: how can I programmaticaly replace all single backslashes with double backslashes in a string. I tried `str.replace("\\","\\\\")` but it gives the same error when parsing.

Comment: From where are you getting this string?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue. After spending a lot of time trying to deal with that quotes I came to this solution

```
@{
  var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
  var obj = new {name = "\"Name1\""};
  var objJson = serializer.Serialize(obj);
}
<script>
  var jsObject = @Html.Raw(objJson);
</script>
```

I use json as js object without any parsing, html result will be like

```
<script>
  var jsObject = {"name":"\"Name1\""} ;
</script>
```

which is correct JavaScript. Hope it will be helpfull for somebody